# Linear transformation problem M2x2 to P2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can you guys help me with this question?

> Let  $T:{M_{2\times2}} \to {P_2}$ be defined by $$T\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}=(a+b-c-d)t^2+ (c+d)t+ (a+b). $$ Find the matrix of T with respect to the standard bases for ${M_{2\times 2}}$ and ${P_2}$.

The standard bases for ${P_2}$ is $$\left\{ {1,t,{t^2}} \right\}$$ and for ${M_{2x2}}$ is $$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0  \\ 
   0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1  \\ 
   0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0  \\
   1 & 0  
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1  
\end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

Comment: Also I'm new to math stack exchange can someone make my question look nicer please?  That would be appreciated!

Comment: What are your standard bases for $M_{2 \times 2}$ and $P_2$? That would be useful information to include in the question....

Comment: The standard bases for $${P_2}$$ is $$\left\{ {1,t,{t^2}} \right\}$$ and for $${M_{2x2}}$$ is $$\left\{ {\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0  \cr 

 } } \right),\left( {\matrix{
   0 & 1  \cr 
   0 & 0  \cr 

 } } \right),\left( {\matrix{
   0 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 0  \cr 

 } } \right),\left( {\matrix{
   0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 1  \cr 

 } } \right)} \right\}$$

Comment: Why doesn't my matrix code work? I literally just copied and paste it from my reply to you and post it to the question!

Comment: @NTT Use `\\ ` rather than `\cr`, and mind the blank lines which trip the `$$ ... $$` blocks.

Comment: Using `\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}` is much easier.

Comment: Hey erfink and dxiv, where did you guys learn which codes to use for this website?? I want to learn so I don't look like a newbie posting questions! Thank you!

Comment: @NTT [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix of a linear transformation comes from expressing each of the basis elements for the domain in terms of basis elements for the range upon applying the transformation.

For example,

$$T \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 1\cdot 1 + 0\cdot t + 1 \cdot t^2.$$
Thus the first column of the matrix for $T$ with respect to these bases will be 
 $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Repeat for the three remaining basis elements of $M_{2 \times 2}$.

**Solution:**

> $$Mat(T) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 &0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 &1  \\ 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\end{bmatrix} $$